# How do i add jquery .live() to this code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a little (and i mean mini) tooltip plugin that i've created but have run into an issue. Basically, it all works fine if instantiated on the dom ready event. However, if I need (as i do) to bring $ajax data onto the page that changes the dom, then my pluggin no longer (for obvious reasons) works.

I don't quite know where in the plugin i'd add the neccessary code to allow it to function correctly (i've tried attaching the live event onto the hover and mousemove events but with eratic results). I DON'T want to have to to reinitialize the tooltip code everytime the $ajax method is run, as there are quite a few different ones involved in the page. I'd rather some sort of 'live' functionality was able to be attached to the tooltip plugin.

Anyway, the full trace can be found here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/jimibt/FLSXv/

hope it twigs/rings a bell somewhere...

**[update]** to re-iterate, adding the live event onto the hover and mousemove events causes eratic results in my 'real' example. i'm looking for an alternative to this. thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply your tooltip, also add a new class such as `hasTooltip`. Then, when you complete your AJAX request look for all `a` elements that do not have the `hasTooltip` class, but do have the `vtip` class, applied and run your `$.tooltip()` function on them.

You can find these new elements like so:

```
$('a.vtip:not(a.hasTooltip)');
```

See [my update](http://www.jsfiddle.net/FLSXv/27/) to your example.

Comment: js - would love to see this in action if you've got the time for a quick (js)fiddle :). would it be possible to add an $ajax complete event inside the plugin, that fired on completion of all ajax events and did the little run that you're referring to?

Comment: js - your a kissable genius - sending one now!! smuschhhh... thank you so much. that is 100% what i was after. musch indebted!! +1 plus answer!!

Comment: ok, ok you can stop now -jeez - only joking, nice one!! actually, i suppose i could embed the not: logic in the constructor and still just call .tooltip()

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial:

```
$(this).live("hover", function(e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</p>");
        $("#tooltip").hide().css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn(1400);
    }, function() {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#tooltip").fadeOut('fast').remove();
    });
    $(this).live("mousemove", function(e) {
        $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
```

Comment: culebrón - yup, agreed. i've already tried this (see my original question) but it works with eratic results in the actual 'real' code that i'm working with. thanks for the message tho. +1 for effort :)

Comment: culebrón - your example (http://www.jsfiddle.net/FLSXv/24/) shows the eratic behaviuor i was refering to :). did that not show in your browser session??